# Expression Changed After it has Been Checked When Using @HostBinding

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a breadcrumb component, I have a service `BreadcrumbService` that has a function that reads the url path and converts them to an array of segments (`this.breadService.getUrlPathSegments()`). When `breadcrumbs` is loaded or updated, I get the following error:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'click-enabled': 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

What is the correct way to handle this? The code works the way I intended, but I need to handle the error message.

What I am trying to do is disable click events on the last item in the breadcrumb list, so when you click on it, none of the events fire. This all works even though I receive the error message.

What I am doing is when the view is checked, update the value of each `breadcurmb`'s `clickable` state. This is done just like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'breadcrumbs',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumbs.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <ng-content select="breadcrumb"></ng-content>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class Breadcrumbs implements AfterViewChecked {
  @Input() disableLast = true;

  @ContentChildren(Breadcrumb, { descendants: false })
  breadcrumbs!: QueryList<Breadcrumb>;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.enableDisableLast();
  }

  enableDisableLast() {
    if (this.breadcrumbs && this.breadcrumbs.length > 0) {
      this.breadcrumbs.forEach(item => { item.clickable = true; });
      this.breadcrumbs.last.clickable = !this.disableLast;
    }
  }
}
```

Next in the breadcrumb I have a `@HostBinding()`, that updates the class of the element. Which is done like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'breadcrumb',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumb.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <button>{{label}}</button>
  `
})
export class Breadcrumb {
  @HostBinding('class.click-enabled')
  get clickEnabled() { return this.clickable; }
}
```

I then combine the two in the component that I am using them with a `forEach` to create the child breadcrumbs. I also listen for navigation changes to re-generate the array of breadcrumb segments to keep the breadcrumb display up-to-date with the current path.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: `
    <breadcrumbs>
      <breadcrumb *ngFor="let crumb of breadcrumbs" [label]="crumb.label|titlecase" [routerLink]="crumb.uri"></breadcrumb>
    </breadcrumbs>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  breadcrumbs: BreadcrumbSegment[] = [];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private breadService: BreadcrumbService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
         // Returns an array formatted as: {label:string; uri:string;}[]
        this.breadcrumbs = this.breadService.getUrlPathSegments();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is the optimal solution, but it is working for my needs. When the `Breadcrumbs` component view is initialized, I set the `QueryList` to dirty, then pipe a delay before I subscribe to the changes. This stops the error from showing up and runs the change detection.

```js
@Component({...})
export class Breadcrumbs implements AfterViewChecked {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Set to dirty so the changes emit at least one time.
    this.breadcrumbs.setDirty();
    this.breadcrumbs.changes.pipe(delay(1)).subscribe(() => {
      this.enableDisableLast();
    });
  }
}
```